# Ensuring Javascript support for multiple libraries (e.g. Angular 1.5, jQuery 2.2.0, ckEditor 4.x, pdfjs 1.3.91)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

We're told "feature detection" is much more betterer than filtering by browsers/versions... so how do you ensure support for specific versions of multiple libraries?!

I don't know what features I'm relying on directly, just what min requirements are for each library!? So when I have a constellation of libraries, what should I do to ensure the user's browser is going to support them all?

EDIT: It seems [here's a partial answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18087207/detecting-browsers-that-are-not-supported-by-jquery-2), but what do you do in your production systems to warn users that their user experience may not be complete due to an old ass browser?

Answer (score 0):

There is a great lib to do the **Feature detection** called: [modernizr](https://modernizr.com/)

However, I wonder how can you know exactly what features are required by those libs?

Usually I would just check the requirements by reading their docs, then I would check [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/) / [ECMAScript Compatibility Table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) to have glance of roughly how many people will be kicked out.

Also, if you use ES6+/CSS3+, [Babel](https://babeljs.io) and [PostCSS](http://postcss.org/) can do some polyfill for you automatically

Comment: The libs generally state IE8+, FFx+, Safari 6+, etc. hence the complete uselessness of feature detection.

Comment: I think IE is the only browser we need to worry about. The rest are all so called ever-green browsers. I personally don't use any polyfills at all in my personal project, because I don't care IE users.